# How do I do a bi-directional look up in Chapel for dictionary-like data?

Tags: python, chapel

In Python, if I have a list I can find the index.  This allows me to keep running IDs as I add things.

```
> things = []
> things.append("spinach")
> things.append("carrots")
> things.index("carrots")
1
```

So give a vegetable (or tuber) I can find an ID for it.  Given an ID, I can find a vegetable (or tuber) to match.

What is the equivalent pattern in Chapel for an unknown number of objects and being able to reference from the name or the id?

Comment: If `things` will be large, you really should use a dictionary to do the reverse mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `push_back` and `find` with 1D rectangular arrays:

```
var A : [1..0] string;
A.push_back("spinach");
A.push_back("carrots");
const (found, idx) = A.find("carrots");
if found then writeln("Found at: ", idx);
// Found at: 2
```

Note that `find` does a linear search, so as @kindall mentioned a dictionary is probably the better choice. In Chapel, that means an associative domain/array:

```
var thingsDom : domain(string);
var things : [thingsDom] int;
var idxToThing : [1..0] string;
// ...
// add a thing
idxToThing.push_back(something);
const newIdx = idxToThing.domain.last;
thingsDom.add(something);
things[something] = newIdx;

assert(idxToThing[things[something]] == something);
```

Two associative arrays would be better if the indices are not in a dense range.